# PHP7.2 cannot suppress NOTICEs in error log

Tags: php, error-handling

NOTICEs are still displaying to error log.

phpinfo() shows:
`error_reporting    22519`

Settings in php-fpm.conf

```
pid = /run/php/php7.2-fpm.pid
error_log = /var/log/php7.2-error.log
rlimit_files = 131072
rlimit_core = 0
include = /etc/php/7.2/fpm/pool.d/*.conf
```

Settings in custom.ini

```
display_errors = Off
display_startup_errors = Off
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
error_log = syslog
expose_php = Off
log_errors = On
fastcgi.error_header = "HTTP/1.0 550 PHP Error"
fastcgi.logging = On
```

What am I missing?   Thanks for your help! :)